# context system call in truss

Tags: multithreading, solaris, truss

While taking the truss of a process in Solaris 10,
I found the below statement

```
<pid>/2:    70.7602 context(1, 0xFC47ABF8)
```

Please explain what this system call `context` means
Also after this call I saw thread 2 behaving like another thread 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ucontext.h>
int getcontext(ucontext_t *ucp);
int setcontext(const ucontext_t *ucp);`
```

These two calls save and restore a context in Solaris.
I do not know positively, as there is no explicit mention of context() in McDougal And Mauro 'Solaris Internals'.
I assume `context()` is the actual kernel call that corresponds these api entry points. 
Perhaps `context(1, <addr> )` corresponds to `getcontext()`, I do not know.

Context switching is how an OS allows a given process to use system resources for a given quantum (time slice).  Part of scheduling.